# Insert contents of href into a URL parameter

Tags: php, html, dom, web-scraping

Here's my problem, say, for example, I have a link on my page, it will look something like:

```
<a href="12/345/67.php">Stuff here</a> - on page 1
```

Simple stuff.

The thing is, when that link is clicked, I need it to write the contents of of the href="" part to a url parameter for page two. So:

```
page2.php?url=12/345/67.php
```

The other problem here is that I'm using the [simple html dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) web scraper to make this page (page 1) so I get my links like this:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.somesite.com/somepage.html');

foreach($html->find('a') as $e)
    $e->style= 'color:#000; padding-left:5px; text-align:left;';
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't this just be a matter of doing something like `$e->href = "page2.php?url={$e->href}"`?

Comment: That made me want to cry. So God damn simple! :( Do you want to put it as an answer so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$href = urlencode($e->href);
$e->href = "page2.php?url=$href";
```